# Model.Item.ElementAt(0) vs Model.Item.LastorDefault() vs Model.Item.Last() in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a MVC model which returns a list with a single Item. In my view I have to reference this Item. As you can see that there are a wide range of options to choose from such as

```
Model.Item.ElementAt(0)
Model.Item.LastorDefault()
Model.Item.Last()
```

Can anyone suggest which method is more preferable in the view and why?

Comment: Let's see, in this case ElementAt and Last are the same, but they will throw an exception if there is nothing. LastOrDefault will just return null.

Comment: LastOrDefault() works as I am not passing a Null item in my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the collection has only one item then use `SingleOrDefault()`. If you're absolutely sure there will be an item then `Single()` will do as well. Using `Single` instead of `First` may cause a little bit (aka negligible) more processing time, but it makes your code much more intention revealing, explicit and fail safe.

```
var whatYouWant = Model.Item.Single();
// Will throw an exception if there is no item or more than one
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis +1 for expanding my options :) I am going to use `First` as in the future I may decide to add more items and in my View the first item will be for editing while the last would be for display only.

Answer (score 2):

These simply do different things:

```
ElementAt(0) // returns the item at index 0, throws an exception if the list is empty
Last() // returns the last item in the list, throws an exception if the list is empty
LastOrDefault() // returns the last item in the list, or the default value for the list element type if the list is empty
```

Since you are asserting that your list has exactly one item, I'd recommend using Model.Items.Single(). Single() throws an exception if the list does not have exactly one item..